# Is it possible to limit the amount of connections invoked on a presigned download url from AWS s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, pre-signed-url

I was wondering if it was possible to limit the amount of usages of a download url to a AWS s3 bucket. As far as I am aware it seem possible for a malicious user to request one download url and spread it to as many hosts as possible and invoke it as many times as can be done at once. This would blow the bandwith costs through the roof possibly.

Is this a realistic scenario? If so, can something be done about it? Aside from setting up your own proxy ofcourse but that would bring a lot of complexity.